# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

Suppose I have these two ctors:

```
public SomeClass(string a, Color? c = null, Font d = null)
        {
            // ...
        }

public SomeClass(string a, Font c = null, Color? d = null)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

~and I do this:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass("Lorem ipsum");
```

I'll get this: "Error 1 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties [...]"

It seems apparent to me that it doesn't matter which one I refer to as the end result is the same (at least in this particular case, and to me that's all that matters right now), so what are my options to getting around this?

EDIT 1:
@oltman: Simplified example.

I just want to be able to write

```
[...] new SomeClass("Lorem", Color.Green)
```

instead of

```
[...] new SomeClass("Lorem", null, Color.Green)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have both, or is this just a simplified example?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Both constructors take the same number of arguments, but in a different order.  Since you have specified default values for the two constructor parameters the compiler cannot distinguish between the two overloads when the second argument is not supplied.

I would advise you to remove the existing constructors and replace with the following:

```
public SomeClass(string a, Color? color, Font font)
{
    // constructor implementation
}

public SomeClass(string a) : this(a, null, null) {}
public SomeClass(string a, Color color) : this(a, color, null) {}
public SomeClass(string a, Font font) : this(a, null, font) {}
```

Comment: This works works wonders and is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

One way to force it to work:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass("Lorem ipsum", (Color?)null, (Font)null);
```

Comment: its very useful when you have only one argument

Comment: @Eli or can't change the ctor.

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect example of `anti-pattern`, the best way avoiding this is @Phil Klein's answer.

Here is another syntax for passing class as null:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass("Lorem ipsum", null as Color, null as Font);
```

Answer (score 2):

## JetBrains Rider IDE issue

In my recent case, JetBrains Rider added a reference to the `project_name` in the `project_name.csproj` producing a self-reference and resulting build errors happening from time to time:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="[project_name]">
    <HintPath>[path_to_dll_file]</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The solution was to just revert this addition.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create another constructor that takes just the string, and update the above constructors to make their second parameters mandatory?

If the idea is that you can construct the object by always supplying the string and then optionally supplying color or font or both, how about this:

```
public SomeClass(string a)
        {
            // ...
        }

public SomeClass(string a, Color? c)
        {
            // ...
        }

public SomeClass(string a, Font f, Color? d = null)
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'll get this: "Error 1 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties [...]"
>
> It seems apparent to me that it doesn't matter which one I refer to as the end result is the same

The call *is* ambiguous.  Each constructor is unique - it doesn't matter if they both create and return an instance, because there could be different logic in each constructor.  The compiler still doesn't know which constructor you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after installing the PnP.Framework, the replacement for SharePointPnPCoreOnline

I was able remove it by uninstalling the SharePointPnPCoreOnline installed from in my project files and tried to clean and build then the error goes away

I hope this helps readers out there who will encounter the same issue as mine

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error could be reported by an extension of your IDE such as OmniSharp,
even though your code compiles / is correct.
This was my case. I restarted it and the false-positive error went away.