# Xamarin - The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I know this is a very common question but I'm unable to understand the basics of this issue. I followed this link [Another stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845494/the-call-is-ambiguous-between-the-following-methods-or-properties) but got lost in the implementation.

I am working on a Xamarin Android application. I have a class having three constructors, each performing different actions.

```
namespace SampleApp.Pages
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // LINES OF CODE
        }

        public HomePage(string abc)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // LINES OF CODE
        }

        public HomePage(int oneId, string xyz, int twoId)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // LINES OF CODE
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am getting error on every `InitializeComponent();` which states:

> Error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'HomePage.InitializeComponent()' and
>   'HomePage.InitializeComponent()'

The above code was working perfectly fine some days ago. This error has occurred suddenly without any change in the code.

What should I do? Also please do tell me if this is just a Visual Studio error.

Comment: Clean, Rebuild and restart visual studio. If you are using extensions like resharper, make sure you clear the cache. Sometimes this is a genuine error, but I've had it occur sometimes when not.

Comment: Place the cursor on InitializeComponent and hit F12, does it present you with a choice to where to go to? If so, pick the first, verify that it is the one you expect, then go back and repeat but pick the other one, see where that is. Also, if you comment out the calls to InitializeComponent, does it compile? If you actually have two such methods, the error list should tell you where they are.

Comment: It compiles, build and run successfully. I cleaned, rebuild and restarted the VS even my mac. But the error is still there. I suppose it must be displayed as a warning not as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked for available updates for Visual Studio and installed all the updates. Issue resolved.